# Error on dask_cudf dataframe while aplying function

Tags: python, python-3.x, dask, dask-dataframe

My data having 1000 features and 1000 samples  has some random values from 0 to 100. where I am applying a  function whose return type is bool on the dask_cudf data frame, but I'm getting an error in the terminal <source missing, REPL/exec in use?>
Any ideas on how to fix this error?
This is the whole code

```
>>>from collections import Counter
>>>import dask_cudf
>>>def change(row, thresholds):
      return 100.0 - (100.0 * Counter(row).most_common(1)[0][1] / len(row)) > thresholds

>>>data = dask_cudf.read_csv("file1.csv")
   data.head()
   Unnamed: 0   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8  ...  990  991  992  993  994  995  996  997  998  999
0           0  68  92  21  43  47  39  78  36  37  ...   15   74   25   16   36   29   76   79   69   45
1           1  97  11  92  54  87  80  37  79  31  ...   20    8   40   53   94    2   22   15   33   78
2           2  20  19  45  29  43  56  25  76   4  ...   42    6   88   95   84   15   31   63   79    7
3           3  91  50  20  37  51  58  81  48  79  ...   28    7   87   64   66    3   59    5   59   44
4           4  32  22  60  52  32   7  87  88  63  ...   94   36   44   59   88   40   79   66   92    4

[5 rows x 1001 columns]

>>> data = data[data.apply(change, axis=1, args=(5.0,), meta=(None, 'bool'))]
>>> data.head()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/software/compilers/anaconda3.9/envs/rapids-22.06/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cudf/core/indexed_frame.py", line 1096, in _apply
    kernel, retty = _compile_or_get(
  File "/home/software/compilers/anaconda3.9/envs/rapids-22.06/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py", line 79, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/software/compilers/anaconda3.9/envs/rapids-22.06/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cudf/core/udf/utils.py", line 202, in _compile_or_get
    kernel, scalar_return_type = kernel_getter(frame, func, args)
  File "/home/software/compilers/anaconda3.9/envs/rapids-22.06/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cudf/core/udf/row_function.py", line 129, in _get_row_kernel
    scalar_return_type = _get_udf_return_type(row_type, func, args)
  File "/home/software/compilers/anaconda3.9/envs/rapids-22.06/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py", line 79, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/software/compilers/anaconda3.9/envs/rapids-22.06/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cudf/core/udf/utils.py", line 53, in _get_udf_return_type
    ptx, output_type = cudautils.compile_udf(func, compile_sig)
  File "/home/software/compilers/anaconda3.9/envs/rapids-22.06/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cudf/utils/cudautils.py", line 248, in compile_udf
    ptx_code, return_type = cuda.compile_ptx_for_current_device(
  File "/home/software/compilers/anaconda3.9/envs/rapids-22.06/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/cuda/compiler.py", line 290, in compile_ptx_for_current_device
    return compile_ptx(pyfunc, args, debug=debug, lineinfo=lineinfo,
  File "/home/software/compilers/anaconda3.9/envs/rapids-22.06/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/compiler_lock.py", line 35, in _acquire_compile_lock
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/software/compilers/anaconda3.9/envs/rapids-22.06/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/cuda/compiler.py", line 267, in compile_ptx
    cres = compile_cuda(pyfunc, None, args, debug=debug, lineinfo=lineinfo,
  File "/home/software/compilers/anaconda3.9/envs/rapids-22.06/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/compiler_lock.py", line 35, in _acquire_compile_lock
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/software/compilers/anaconda3.9/envs/rapids-22.06/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/cuda/compiler.py", line 202, in compile_cuda
    cres = compiler.compile_extra(typingctx=typingctx,
  File "/home/software/compilers/anaconda3.9/envs/rapids-22.06/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/compiler.py", line 693, in compile_extra
    return pipeline.compile_extra(func)
  File "/home/software/compilers/anaconda3.9/envs/rapids-22.06/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/compiler.py", line 429, in compile_extra
    return self._compile_bytecode()
  File "/home/software/compilers/anaconda3.9/envs/rapids-22.06/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/compiler.py", line 497, in _compile_bytecode
    return self._compile_core()
  File "/home/software/compilers/anaconda3.9/envs/rapids-22.06/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/compiler.py", line 476, in _compile_core
    raise e
  File "/home/software/compilers/anaconda3.9/envs/rapids-22.06/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/compiler.py", line 463, in _compile_core
    pm.run(self.state)
  File "/home/software/compilers/anaconda3.9/envs/rapids-22.06/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/compiler_machinery.py", line 353, in run
    raise patched_exception
  File "/home/software/compilers/anaconda3.9/envs/rapids-22.06/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/compiler_machinery.py", line 341, in run
    self._runPass(idx, pass_inst, state)
  File "/home/software/compilers/anaconda3.9/envs/rapids-22.06/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/compiler_lock.py", line 35, in _acquire_compile_lock
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/software/compilers/anaconda3.9/envs/rapids-22.06/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/compiler_machinery.py", line 296, in _runPass
    mutated |= check(pss.run_pass, internal_state)
  File "/home/software/compilers/anaconda3.9/envs/rapids-22.06/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/compiler_machinery.py", line 269, in check
    mangled = func(compiler_state)
  File "/home/software/compilers/anaconda3.9/envs/rapids-22.06/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/typed_passes.py", line 105, in run_pass
    typemap, return_type, calltypes, errs = type_inference_stage(
  File "/home/software/compilers/anaconda3.9/envs/rapids-22.06/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/typed_passes.py", line 81, in type_inference_stage
    infer.build_constraint()
  File "/home/software/compilers/anaconda3.9/envs/rapids-22.06/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/typeinfer.py", line 1039, in build_constraint
    self.constrain_statement(inst)
  File "/home/software/compilers/anaconda3.9/envs/rapids-22.06/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/typeinfer.py", line 1386, in constrain_statement
    self.typeof_assign(inst)
  File "/home/software/compilers/anaconda3.9/envs/rapids-22.06/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/typeinfer.py", line 1459, in typeof_assign
    self.typeof_global(inst, inst.target, value)
  File "/home/software/compilers/anaconda3.9/envs/rapids-22.06/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/typeinfer.py", line 1559, in typeof_global
    typ = self.resolve_value_type(inst, gvar.value)
  File "/home/software/compilers/anaconda3.9/envs/rapids-22.06/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/typeinfer.py", line 1480, in resolve_value_type
    raise TypingError(msg, loc=inst.loc)
numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in cuda mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Untyped global name 'Counter': Cannot determine Numba type of <class 'type'>

File "<stdin>", line 2:
<source missing, REPL/exec in use?>


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/software/compilers/anaconda3.9/envs/rapids-22.06/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dask/dataframe/core.py", line 1219, in head
    return self._head(n=n, npartitions=npartitions, compute=compute, safe=safe)
  File "/home/software/compilers/anaconda3.9/envs/rapids-22.06/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dask/dataframe/core.py", line 1253, in _head
    result = result.compute()
  File "/home/software/compilers/anaconda3.9/envs/rapids-22.06/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dask/base.py", line 312, in compute
    (result,) = compute(self, traverse=False, **kwargs)
  File "/home/software/compilers/anaconda3.9/envs/rapids-22.06/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dask/base.py", line 600, in compute
    results = schedule(dsk, keys, **kwargs)
  File "/home/software/compilers/anaconda3.9/envs/rapids-22.06/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dask/local.py", line 554, in get_sync
    return get_async(
  File "/home/software/compilers/anaconda3.9/envs/rapids-22.06/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dask/local.py", line 497, in get_async
    for key, res_info, failed in queue_get(queue).result():
  File "/home/software/compilers/anaconda3.9/envs/rapids-22.06/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 439, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "/home/software/compilers/anaconda3.9/envs/rapids-22.06/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 391, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "/home/software/compilers/anaconda3.9/envs/rapids-22.06/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dask/local.py", line 539, in submit
    fut.set_result(fn(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/home/software/compilers/anaconda3.9/envs/rapids-22.06/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dask/local.py", line 235, in batch_execute_tasks
    return [execute_task(*a) for a in it]
  File "/home/software/compilers/anaconda3.9/envs/rapids-22.06/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dask/local.py", line 235, in <listcomp>
    return [execute_task(*a) for a in it]
  File "/home/software/compilers/anaconda3.9/envs/rapids-22.06/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dask/local.py", line 226, in execute_task
    result = pack_exception(e, dumps)
  File "/home/software/compilers/anaconda3.9/envs/rapids-22.06/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dask/local.py", line 221, in execute_task
    result = _execute_task(task, data)
  File "/home/software/compilers/anaconda3.9/envs/rapids-22.06/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dask/core.py", line 119, in _execute_task
    return func(*(_execute_task(a, cache) for a in args))
  File "/home/software/compilers/anaconda3.9/envs/rapids-22.06/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dask/optimization.py", line 990, in __call__
    return core.get(self.dsk, self.outkey, dict(zip(self.inkeys, args)))
  File "/home/software/compilers/anaconda3.9/envs/rapids-22.06/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dask/core.py", line 149, in get
    result = _execute_task(task, cache)
  File "/home/software/compilers/anaconda3.9/envs/rapids-22.06/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dask/core.py", line 119, in _execute_task
    return func(*(_execute_task(a, cache) for a in args))
  File "/home/software/compilers/anaconda3.9/envs/rapids-22.06/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dask/core.py", line 119, in <genexpr>
    return func(*(_execute_task(a, cache) for a in args))
  File "/home/software/compilers/anaconda3.9/envs/rapids-22.06/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dask/core.py", line 119, in _execute_task
    return func(*(_execute_task(a, cache) for a in args))
  File "/home/software/compilers/anaconda3.9/envs/rapids-22.06/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dask/utils.py", line 41, in apply
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/software/compilers/anaconda3.9/envs/rapids-22.06/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dask/dataframe/core.py", line 6533, in apply_and_enforce
    df = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/software/compilers/anaconda3.9/envs/rapids-22.06/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dask/utils.py", line 1053, in __call__
    return getattr(__obj, self.method)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/software/compilers/anaconda3.9/envs/rapids-22.06/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py", line 79, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/software/compilers/anaconda3.9/envs/rapids-22.06/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cudf/core/dataframe.py", line 3826, in apply
    return self._apply(func, _get_row_kernel, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/software/compilers/anaconda3.9/envs/rapids-22.06/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py", line 79, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/software/compilers/anaconda3.9/envs/rapids-22.06/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cudf/core/indexed_frame.py", line 1100, in _apply
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: user defined function compilation failed.
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error is 3 lines above `Untyped global name 'Counter': Cannot determine Numba type of <class 'type'>`.  Numba needs to know the function and cannot just import from an external library like that.

The better solution is that you can skip the `apply` and use `.mode()` to find the most common integer from the pandas/dask API.  https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/generated/dask.dataframe.DataFrame.mode.html

However, cuDF has incorrect documentation, keeping it from emulating the pandas example below, and I made a docs request.  https://github.com/rapidsai/cudf/issues/11570

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(4,10,size=(15, 10)), columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJ'))
lrow = len(df.columns) # so you don't need to recalc this every run :)
print(df.mode(axis = 1)[0]) #it sometimes created a few columns for me
output = 100.0 - (100.0 * df.mode(axis = 1)[0] / lrow) > 5
print(output)
```

In your next q, please include the data or a way to generate the data :)